# ssh: how to connect a intranet machine outside the intranet

Tags: ssh

I have a machine running my computing tasks in the intranet, and I want to connect the machine outside the intranet via `ssh`. But I don't know how to do it. Since `ssh` can only connect machines in `LAN` or machines with private ip.

Comment: Talk with your IT department and get VPN access from the outside.

Comment: Alternately; `ssh` is not limited to only connecting to machines on a LAN or with private IPs, and if it looks like that, then SSH port 22 is blocked for outbound traffic on a network firewall. Talk with your IT department and ask if that can be changed for your intranet machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `NAT` (Network Translating Address) to redirect a port from internet IP + port to your computer internal IP + port

For example you can use  externalIP:777 from internet to connect on 192.168.0.100:22 intranet machine

To connect with ssh on different port using ssh command : `ssh ${IP_or_Domain} -p ${Port}`